# dplyr code "df %>% group_by(date = cut(date, breaks = "1 hour"))" no longer produces the desired result?

Tags: r, datetime, group-by, dplyr, summarize

I have been using the following dplyr code to generate hourly averages from 1-minute time-series data. The code has been working for months, but has recently been producing some problematic results. Has something changed with any of the following functions: `group_by()`, `cut()`, or `summarise()`?

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1505187300, 1505187360, 1505187420, 1505187480, 1505187540, 1505187600, 1505187660, 1505187720, 1505201580, 1505201640), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), co = c(0.149,0.149,0.149, 0.106, 0.149, 0.149, 0.192, 0.149, 0.149, 0.149), co2 = c(544L, 545L, 544L, 543L, 546L, 546L, 548L, 547L, 549L, 554L), VOC = c(22.55, 22.55, 22.8198, 23.2602, 22.9501, 23.2154, 23.4262, 23.0231, 23.0525, 22.7911), RH = c(77.02, 76.9, 77.2, 76.6, 76.99, 76.83, 77.13, 77.81, 77.48, 77.1), ugm3 = c(12.862, 13.408, 14.188, 12.342, 13.278, 12.81, 10.834, 13.018, 12.992, 12.498), temp = c(62.06, 62.02, 62.02, 61.98, 61.94, 61.9, 61.86, 61.78, 61.8, 61.8)), .Names = c("date", "co", "co2", "VOC", "RH", "ugm3", "temp"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

new_df <- df %>% 
    group_by(date = cut(date, breaks = "1 hour")) %>%
    summarize(co = mean(co), co2 = mean(co2), VOC = mean(VOC), RH = mean(RH), ugm3 = mean(ugm3), temp = mean(temp))

new_df
```

**Expected output:**

```
expected_output <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 5L), .Label = c("2017-09-12 03:00:00", "2017-09-12 04:00:00", "2017-09-12 05:00:00", "2017-09-12 06:00:00", "2017-09-12 07:00:00"), class = "factor"), co = c(0.149, 0.149), co2 = c(545.375, 551.5), VOC = c(22.97435, 22.9218), RH = c(77.06, 77.29), ugm3 = c(12.8425, 12.745), temp = c(61.945, 61.8)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("date", "co", "co2", "VOC", "RH", "ugm3", "temp"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

**Actual output:**

```
actual_output <- structure(list(co = 0.149, co2 = 546.6, VOC = 22.96384, RH = 77.106, ugm3 = 12.823, temp = 61.916), .Names = c("co", "co2", "VOC", "RH", "ugm3", "temp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Prior to this week, this code would have generated a new `df` with two observations, one for the `03:00:00` hour, and one for the `07:00:00` hour. While the `group_by()` function appears to be assigning the new hourly timestamps correctly, the `summarize()` function is not behaving properly. Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

If there are more robust alternatives to aggregating time-series data into specific intervals, I'm all ears!

Comment: I get your expected output, can you share what you get ?

Comment: Good idea, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: it's as if the group_by was skipped

Comment: If you look at the output from `group_by()` before passing it to `summarize()`, it looks good. I think it has something to do with `summarize()` instead...

Comment: try to replace `group_by` by `dplyr::group_by`

Comment: and `summarize` by `dplyr::summarize`

Comment: I bet you loaded `plyr` after `dplyr`;)

Comment: You're exactly right. `dplyr::summarize()` did the trick! Rookie mistake on my part, but I'm just glad my data pipeline is up and running again! Thank you! Feel free to provide the solution in an Answer if you want those internet points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You loaded `plyr` after `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
# ...
library(plyr)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------# -------------------------------------------
# 
# Attachement du package : ‘plyr’
# 
# The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
# 
#     arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise, summarize
```

We should always read those warnings :). Now let's see what happens:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(date = cut(date, breaks = "1 hour")) %>%
   summarize(co = mean(co), co2 = mean(co2), VOC = mean(VOC), RH = mean(RH), ugm3 = mean(ugm3), temp = mean(temp))
#     co   co2      VOC     RH   ugm3   temp
# 1 0.149 546.6 22.96384 77.106 12.823 61.916
```

If you load `dplyr` after `plyr`, or use `dplyr::summarize`, you'll have the expected behavior.

```
df %>% 
   group_by(date = cut(date, breaks = "1 hour")) %>%
   dplyr::summarize(co = mean(co), co2 = mean(co2), VOC = mean(VOC), RH = mean(RH), ugm3 = mean(ugm3), temp = mean(temp))
# # A tibble: 2 x 7
#                  date    co     co2      VOC    RH    ugm3   temp
#                <fctr> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2017-09-12 03:00:00 0.149 545.375 22.97435 77.06 12.8425 61.945
# 2 2017-09-12 07:00:00 0.149 551.500 22.92180 77.29 12.7450 61.800
```